# JavaScript - Checking string

Tags: javascript

Hi
I want to check if every words of the current URL path is match with my expected string.
The current URL http://www.example.com/category/product/htc-desire

```
var path = location.pathname;
the path must match every words of "/category/product/htc-desire"
```

How can I do it, thanks.

Comment: what value does the path variable have?

Comment: You want to match the strings after the first `/` meaning the URL without the domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var path = location.path;
alert("/category/product/htc-desire" === path.replace("http://www.example.com", ""));
//should be true
```

Or am I missing the point?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `var path = location.pathname`.

```
path.indexOf(pattern) === 0
```

matches all paths starting with the pattern.

However, with url's, you'll also want to be case insensitive.  In that case:

```
path.toLowerCase().indexOf(pattern.toLowerCase()) === 0
```

If you want an *exact* match:

```
path.toLowerCase() === pattern.toLowerCase()
```

Comment: should I use for loop to check and how?

Comment: Use a for-loop if you want to repeatedly doing something.  It is completely unrelated to your question and what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry that I mean using for loop to match two string, e.g. var a = abcdef; var b = abcdee; then use for loop on each string to loop every character to compare is it all characters are consistent or inconsistent

Comment: If you just want to compare all characters, you can simply do `(a === b)` which will compare the two strings if a and b are both strings.  This is standard JavaScript.  However, for *case-insensitive* comparisons, you need to do `(a.toLowerCase() === b.toLowerCase())`